# Does typescript support spread syntax in .d.ts?

Tags: typescript

How to get all `key: type` from a implemented class and spread them into an existing interface?

Here is my example with `egg`:

```
// Controller.ts
import { Controller as EggController } from 'egg'

export default class MyController extends EggController {
  myCustomMethod() {

  }
}

// index.d.ts
import MyController from 'Controller.ts'

declare module 'egg' {
  interface Controller {
    // I want to get 'key: type' definition from MyController and spread them here,
    // that every interface extending from egg.Controller will include my extends.
  }
}

// controller/*.ts
import { Controller } from 'egg'

class BusinessController extends Controller {
  getProfile() {
    this.MyCustomMethod() // This should work rather than missing.
  }
}
```

At a word, how to merge MyController into egg.Controller in `.d.ts`?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The question about spread types in TS is interesting, but may be an `XY` problem. I don't understand your example though - it looks like `egg` library `Controller` wants to extend you project's `MyController` which circularly extends `Controller` from `egg` again. That wouldn't make that much sense from an architecture perspective. Could you simplify your example?

Comment: @ford04 I have updated my description. `MyController` does extend from `egg.Controller`, that's why  I want `egg.Controller` has my property in it. But if I write `interface Controller extends MyController`, that will prompt `class Controller extends from it self`, that's why I just want `key: type` in definition but not extends from it. Thanks.